/give command only works with certain items
I am playing Minecraft on a Nintendo Switch (creative mode with cheats activated) and I am trying to give a barrier block, but for some reason that doesn't work. I am using the command:
/give MYMINECRAFTNAME barrier

and I get a "syntax error unexpected >>barrier<<"
If I do the same with tnt or diamond it works just fine.
Why doesn't this command work and how can I get it to work?

If the answer in the duplicate question doesn't work, something might have changed in a recent update

Thank you very much for your response! As pointed out in the response to the duplicate question I tried /give@s b to see all the items listed that are available and barrier was not listed. The version of minecraft listed when starting up the program is v.1.2.12 (build April 2018). So maybe I would have to update in order to get it. I have to find out how to do this. Anyways, thanks a lot, I learned so much!

We had the same error and only needed to upgrade Minecraft. For this connect your Switch to the internet and restart the game to allow the update to be downloaded and installed.

To give yourself a barrier via command, you type:
/give @s minecraft:barrier
Notice that minecraft: is behind barrier. minecraft:barrier is the valid name for giving yourself a barrier via the give command. Hope this helps!

Thank you for your response! As mentioned above, it looks like I might have an old version and the block is not available.
